# Copy only text from excel worksheet to another

Tags: python, excel, text, copy, openpyxl

Good morning,
Using a python application, I would like to copy only cells text from one excel file to another excel file, where the boxes are formatted appropriately.
For now I have this code but I am not satisfied as it does not respect the formatting of the final end.

```
import openpyxl as xl

path1 = '.\Test_files\monats.xlsx'
path2 = '.\Test_files\Vorlage.xlsx'

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2['Vcdorlage']

for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

wb2.save(path2)
```

Comment: If you're only copying the data, why do you think the formatting should be copied as well.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the formatting of cells from the source worksheet to the destination worksheet, you can probably just assign them like you do with the `value` field. So something like this perhaps:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from copy import copy

path1 = '.\Test_files\monats.xlsx'
path2 = '.\Test_files\Vorlage.xlsx'

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2['Vcdorlage']

for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        new_cell = ws2[cell.coordinate]
        new_cell.value = cell.value
        new_cell.number_format = cell.number_format
        if cell.has_style:
            new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
            new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
            new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
            new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)

wb2.save(path2)
```

In this code, we are copying the font, border, fill, number format, and alignment of each cell in addition to its value.

Comment: This is indeed the canonical approach. However, as style creation is slow, it should be avoided if possible from within loops. Most formatting will be applied for whole rows or columns.